# Change upvote tooltip to prevent irrelevant but "useful" answers

Tags: feature-request

I sometimes see answers upvoted despite being irrelevant/unhelpful to the question. These answers have useful information and as such get upvotes. But their usefulness is general. Like a random blog post. They don't answer the question, and even obstruct the question getting answered because people see the question has been "answered".

The current tooltip encourages these upvotes.

Comment: What would you suggest it be changed to? The current wording is "This answer is useful."

Comment: @KevinB That's a good question. I'm hoping that someone with better qualification than I can answer that. (And I _am_ referring to `useful` answers. Just not useful to the question they're answering.)

Comment: I would like it to say "this answer is not low quality", but.... i wouldn't want "meh" quality answers upvoted either. "high quality" is... a bit weird i think, because an answer doesn't have to be high quality to answer the question. I think "useful" does the job.

Comment: @KevinB "this answer is not low quality" would not help. It should be something like "this answer answers the question".

Comment: Got any examples? I'm kinda struggling to find answers I'd characterize as "useful" without actually answering the question.

Comment: @Shog9 Both answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33692322/how-can-a-universal-windows-app-have-multiple-independent-windows-like-microsof are helpful for someone working on UWP windows. They aren't, however, relevant at all to the question.

Comment: I have an answer that fits that same criteria: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790752/callback-of-animate-gets-called-twice-jquery/8791175#8791175 it's very useful to people who would generally be searching for what is in the title of the question, but my answer doesn't really answer the question that was asked, the accepted answer does.

Comment: @KevinB +1 for honesty!

Comment: Honesty, or self promotion, whatever you want to call it. :) point being, I think the example shows that just because the answer doesn't answer the question being asked, doesn't mean it won't help a lot of future visitors, which is what I think upvotes should be reserved for: answers that are useful (which usually coincides with answers that answered the question that the user searching has, but not always the question asked by the op.)

Comment: Oh, this is the old "folks posting their Google results and hoping it helps" problem. Folks do it because the chance of random upvotes is slightly higher than the chance of deserved downvotes... So don't be stingy with your downvotes.

Comment: sometimes a good answer doesn't answer the question because the question is wrong....and a good answer will say why it's wrong, what a better question would be, and give the answer to that.  I've had many answers both upvoted AND accepted doing exactly that...and i'm sure i'm not alone in that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm skeptical that most voters actually read that tooltip... But even if they do, finding a more applicable word is gonna be hard; trying to split the hair between "generally useful to readers" and "useful to folks with this problem" is gonna result in a subtlety that will be lost on most readers.

The real problem here isn't that folks are posting really useful answers on all the wrong questions... It's folks posting answers that *look* like they might be relevant, in hope of getting lucky and accidentally posting a useful solution. This technique predates Stack Overflow, voting, and the tooltip, so I'm not particularly optimistic that changing a bit of (perfectly-reasonable) guidance will do anything to stop it.

The bigger problem is that *people are reluctant to downvote blatantly wrong answers.* So when some well-intentioned but clueless reader upvotes them, they can end up *looking* like they were useful... Even though it was probably just someone trying to be nice.

Best advice I can give is... Don't be stingy with your downvotes. If you see a wrong answer, make sure you mark it as such. And don't delude yourself that a completely irrelevant answer might be "useful to someone" - I have a good recipe for waffles that'd be useful to all sorts of people, but if I started posting it under every question on Stack Overflow I'd hope you'd be downvoting them.

Comment: Downvoting waffles??

Comment: Unthinkable, right? What could *possibly* be more useful than waffles! Unless you're looking for a specific Windows windowing solution or something.

Comment: To that person I'd say, "Look in front of you now. Do *you* have a waffle? *Wouldn't you be happier if you did*?"

Comment: Feature request: change upvote tooltip to "This answer is TOTALLY WAFFLES!!!!!"